# Run-time codepaths without function pointers in C?

Tags: c, optimization, c99

I understand this might not be a real question. But I'm here looking at my fresh code I' starting to write and was wondering about something.

I have to write code that usually needs to be run on several platforms. I approach this, always, in two ways.

When there's sufficient platform differences that there's almost a complete code rewrite, then I have separate directories for those modules for platforms with said platform code in it and I compile in source from directory depending on the platform.

for example:

```
|-- module_a
|-- module_b
|   |-- linux
|   |-- osx
|   `-- windows
`-- module_c
```

Makefile would call in source from module_b that's platform-agnostic and module_b/[os]/ code depending on the platform.

This is all fine and cool unless there's not all that much code to be rewritten. This, then, tends to lead to a lot of copy/pasting which I tend to avoid because it can lead to errors and, frankly, feels clumsy.

This second variant also overlaps with a problem that I have where I sometimes need to have optimized and unoptimized versions (don't ask) of same code and situations that are similar. Which led me to function pointers.

This, second problem resolution, also works fine. However, I understand function pointers can lead to problems with compiler not really being happy when it comes to optimizing code.

My new code will have a lot of these so I am wondering, in advance, if there is maybe a third possibility to have run-time codepaths that are compiler (and maybe cpu?) friendly?

Note that I avoid using #ifdefs for this at all. 
If it matters, I'm programming in C99 with gcc 5.2 (and snapshots) on all three platforms (yes, even OSX). So I'm open to extensions as well.

PS
I've tried programmers.stack several times, but it's a ghost town, sadly.

Comment: Please don't criticise other platforms that fail to provide an answer for a poorly asked question. Who do you think we are, some kind of oracle? Where is the code that, in advance, you are trying to write?

Comment: why avoid `#ifdef`? For the stuff that can be determined statically, that's the best way.

Comment: @Adam #ifdefs are more or less the same thing I'm doing with conditional makefiles, so they're unnecessary in my case. Maybe avoiding was not the right word to use. Not using more like it. It wouldn't replace runtime reconfiguration need that function pointers provide anyways.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not quite following you. Why do you need run-time dispatch for platform abstraction? If you need to switch in an optional unoptimized implementation, say because the fast path relies on unavailable CPU instructions, then feel free to do so but in the typical OS portability case you are usually best off directly implementing the function for each supported platform. If there's still a lot of shared code around then shunt that off to shared helpers or what not, or conversely use `#ifdef` if the differences are tiny.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was preemptive before I get redirected to that site. If question needs to be closed, so be it. No code for new codebase yet - I'm looking at what I wrote in past projects and am sitting in-front of a new task I need to do and am wondering if I can avoid function pointers altogether now. More like a rule, structs filled with them like an API if you will.

Comment: @doynax that's exactly what I use function pointers for. Sometimes I need an optimized path, sometimes not because CPU doesn't support it (or other hardware I use for image processing). I was wondering if there's a way to have runtime reconfiguration without function pointers though that would be compiler friendly.

Comment: @Keyframe: Usually the issue is that small individual computations don't leave the optimizer much to work with, and so you need to recompile larger segments containing the outer loops multiple times. Typically by compiling and linking in multiple shared library versions of the critical loops such that the optimizer options may be individually tuned for each.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any run-time code path switching for the sake of different platforms, if separate binaries can be compiled for each platform.

Run-time control flow for platform support is only required if you build the same image for multiple pieces of hardware (based on the same processor, obviously) and just configure it with different modules selected at run time. This allows a module to appear in several different flavors, yet be called using ordinary global function calls, rather than indirectly via function pointers.

Comment: OK, but how would you configure and select modules/code at run time without function pointers using ordinary global function calls? Let's assume .so/.dll is not an option

Comment: You wouldn't. *Before* run time, you'd need some script to link those pieces stuff together to make an image (the correct image for a given system board or whatever).